# How to add a consistent variable or function to every AngularJS $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I made an App (build using AngularJS 1.X) that has a lot of directives, most of which have there own isolated scope.  So, for every new `$scope` i assign `Underscore.js` + `Underscore.string` variables `_` and `s` to them, like so:

```
controller: function($scope){
  $scope._ = _;
  $scope._s = s;
  $scope.foo = 'my-example-here';
}
```

Then do some cool stuff like this within there isolated scope templates:

```
<div ng-bind='s.humanize(some_id)'></div> # output: "My example here"
```

Unfortunately you cannot access global variables in these scopes.

So, ultimately, how to add a consistent variable or function to every AngularJS `$scope`?

Comment: Have you tried $rootScope?

Comment: Not yet, but how?  Here's what i just tried `.directive('body', function($rootScope){return {controller:function(){ $rootScope.derp = "foo!"; }}})`.  But i was not able to see `derp` from an isolated scope.  Or, did it wrong.

Comment: The John Papa Style Guide recommends constants for that purpose https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#constants

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.derp = "foo!";
});

app.directive('myDir', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        scope { ... },
        controller: function($rootScope) {
            console.log($rootScope.derp);
        }
    };
});
```

Make sure to put `ng-controller="MyCtrl"` directive somewhere on the parent DOM element of your custom directive like so:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div my-dir></div>
</div>
```

Try it please.

EDIT
Also, you can use [constants](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#constants) as described by @georgeawg in comment.

Comment: Hi, this works, but is accessing it through `$rootScope` my only choice?

Comment: Updated the answer